# text not appearing after div

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make text appear after the div element containing the background image but no text is appearing underneath it. I'm not sure what to add, the paragraph isn't there and I've tried multiple styes for "this is a test".

```
<div id="opener">
<p id="introText">
Adam Ginther is a<class id="blueText"> front-end developer</class> with an interest in responsive & mobile design
</p>
</div>
<br>
<div id="bottomOpener">
<p id="awesome">
I'm also 100% awesome
</p>
</div>
<p> This is a test</p>


/*  first.css */
body {
    background-color: black;
    font-family: 'Fenix', serif;
}
#opener {
    background-image: url('../images/background.jpg');
    background-color: #373737;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-attachment:fixed;
    background-position:center;
    height: 800px;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    text-align: center;
}
#introText {
    width: 400px;
    height: 40px;
    margin-left: 200px;
    left: 20%;
    color: #ececec;
    background-color: black;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 50px 80px 50px 80px;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    /* black, 50% opacity */
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
    position: absolute;
}
#blueText {
    color:#00aeff;
}
#awesome {
    color: white;
}
#bottomOpener {
    background-color: white;
}
p {
    color: green;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Most likely, your text is hidden underneath your `position: fixed;` image. You could make it `position: static;` instead, or adjust the location of your paragraphs. If you had a jsFiddle, we could test your situation further.

Comment: Well `position: static` is the default, so no need to specify it in that case. http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/

Comment: Yes, Whistletoe is right, you don't actually need to specity position: static; because its default, and you could also use position: relative; instead.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `position: fixed` on the `#opener` element it is extracted from the normal flow of the document and displayed on top of the rest of the content. The p-element you want to see is thus hidden beneath.

Answer (score 0):

Your text is behind your `intro`, as said in other answers. Here's a fiddle that fixes it http://jsfiddle.net/ASd33/ by adding `z-index: -1` to your `#opener` .

Note that this is not a good solution, but it is good enough for you to debug.